# how to access variables from struct in the main function

Tags: c

So I wanna create an agenda for numbers and names and all that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Agenda
{
    char name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int number[11];
    int index;
}Agenda;
int main(){

    int i,j,n,m,f,nb;
    int TABL_Agenda[m][n];
    Agenda;

    printf("give the number of ocntacts you want to have: ");
    scanf("%d", &nb);
    for ( i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nName: ");
            scanf("%s", );
            printf("last name: ");
            scanf("%s", );
            printf("Number: ");
            scanf("%d", );
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is my code and I want the user to enter names and all that information and store it int variable in the struct like when he enter the name it is stored in the struct and I want to turn it into an array

Comment: `int TABL_Agenda[m][n];` - `m` and `n` are uninitialized.

Comment: Is `TABL_Agenda` meant to be an array of Agenda structures?

Comment: Do you want a 2D array of your struct?

Comment: your declaration of TABL_Agenda is not what you want. But start with a simpler problem, just declare one instance of your struct and fill that. You should do that without user input, it will save you time as you test. Once that it is working, add array support and lastly add user input.

Answer (score 0):

first note that you are using uninitialized  `m` and `n`.

second your `return 0` is inside of your loop `for ( i = 0; i < nb; i++)` , which will cause program to end within of your loop.

also if you want a 2D array of your struct this will help:

```
typedef struct Agenda
{
    char name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int number[11];
    int index; 
}Agenda;
int main()
{

    int i, j, n = 5, m = 5, f, nb;
    int TABL_Agenda[m][n];


    printf("give the number of ocntacts you want to have: ");
    scanf("%d", &nb);
    Agenda one[nb][4];
    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nName: ");
            scanf("%s", one[i][j].name);
            printf("last name: ");
            scanf("%s", one[i][j].last_name);
            printf("Number: ");
            scanf("%d", one[i][j].number);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to store all the data in a 2D array so when I want to print all the data it can be ordered and also it will help me get any number or name by just the index

Comment: @Yahya what is this index exactly like? `[1] [1]` also what do you mean by `be ordered`?

Comment: the index like a reference number when the like enter 2 it will give him the second contact in his agenda, and I wanted to access through the index of the array

Comment: @Yahya why do you need 2D array?

Comment: @i want to order the data like doing a matrix of n line and 3 rows one row for name second for last name and third for the number phone